# Emulating an HID device with a raspberry pi 5

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi5

I am trying to use my raspberry pi 5 model B rev 1.0 to emulate an HID device so i can later use a python script with gpiozero to send keypresses via buttons on gpio.

I have already tried to use many tutorials to do this but keep hitting brick walls, I've tried to use tutorials that say they are compatible with the pi 4 as I could imagine that would be the closest compatibility I could get. I am using a usb-c splitter (one for power one for data) to connect to my windows computer. I've tried to use two tutorials those being isticktoit.net's tutorial (https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383) however this never worked and it seemed a bit to complex to control from a python script. I then tried to use key-mime-pi (https://mtlynch.io/key-mime-pi/) which appealed to me as it uses python so I figured it could be implemented easier but it also never worked (specifically a conflicting version error in the requirements.txt). is there any other ways to do this with a pi 5 or is it impossible with a pi 5?